# SQL Get List of Users not in Roles

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables:

1. Users :  UserID, UserName
2. Roles :  RoleID, RoleName
3. UsersInRoles : UserID, RoleID

How do I get a list of UserIDs and the RolesIDs for which they are NOT in?

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Aaron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select users.userid, roles.roleid
    from users
    cross join roles
    left outer join usersinroles on
        usersinroles.userid = users.userid and
        usersinroles.roleid = roles.roleid
    where usersinroles.userid is null
```

`cross join` joins each role to each user.

`left outer join` joins the tables, but doesn't delete the rows that don't match.  Instead, it leaves the joined fields as null when there is no match.  Getting *only* the cases where the field is null has the effect of getting only the rows that do not match--the roles that a user doesn't have.

Answer (score 1):

I think @dan1111's solution is better, but this one might be more readable:

```
SELECT u.Userame,
    r.RoleName
FROM Users u
CROSS JOIN Roles r

EXCEPT

SELECT u.Userame,
    r.RoleName
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN UsersInRoles ur
    on u.UserID = ur.UserID
INNER JOIN Roles r
    on ur.RoleID = r.RoleID
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a LEFT JOIN and combine it with an IS NULL condition.

Answer (score 0):

This works using a `CROSS JOIN` and a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT U.UserId, R.RoleId
FROM Roles R CROSS JOIN Users U
   LEFT JOIN UserRoles UR ON U.UserId = UR.UserId AND R.RoleId = UR.RoleId
WHERE UR.UserId IS NULL
```

And here is the sample Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/46e48/1